# Allow $2 \Bbb N$ to denote the even integers $> 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Please help!

Allow $2\Bbb N$ to denote the even integers $> 0$. Say $a \in 2\Bbb N$ is irreducible if there are no numbers $b, c \in 2\Bbb N$ so that $a = bc$.

**(1)** Show that if $n$ is an odd number, then $2n$ is in $2\Bbb N$ and is irreducible. Conversely, show that every irreducible number in $2\Bbb N$ is twice an odd number.

**(2)** Show that every number $a$ in $2\Bbb N$ factors into a product of irreducible numbers in $2\Bbb N$.

**(3)** Show that factorization of numbers in $2\Bbb N$ into products of irreducibles in $2\Bbb N$ is not unique.

Comment: It is *sometimes* unique, but not always. For example $36=2\times 18=6\times 6$.

Comment: For the first two, consider the usual factorization of $n$.

Comment: @user160999: I have reverted your edit. It is **very** impolite, and borderline dishonest, to alter the question so dramatically once it has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

(1) If $a$ is twice an odd number, then $a$ is divisible by $2$ but not by $4$.  Then $a$ is obviously irreducible in $2\mathbb{N}$, since if $a=xy$ with $x$ and $y$ in $2\mathbb{N}$, then each of $x$ and $y$ is divisible by $2$, and therefore $4$ divides $xy$.

Conversely, if $4$ divides $a$, let $a=4b$. Then $a=(2)(2b)$, so $a$ is not irreducible.

(2) This is the usual (strong) induction proof. Suppose that for all $2w\in 2\mathbb{N}$ such that $2w\lt 2n$, the number $2w$ can be expressed as a product of numbers in $2\mathbb{N}$ that are irreducible in $2\mathbb{N}$. We show that $2n$ is a product of irreducibles.  If $2n$ is irreducible, there is nothing to do. Otherwise, $2n=(2x)(2y)$ for some positive integers $x$ and $y$. By the induction assumption, $2x$ and $2y$ are products of irreducibles in $2\mathbb{N}$, and therefore so is $(2x)(2y)$.

(3) *Sometimes* the representation is (essentially) unique. But for example $36=(2)(18)=(6)(6)$, and $2$, $18$, and $6$ are all irreducible in $2\mathbb{N}$.

**Remark:** The point of this problem is that the Unique Factorization Theorem for natural numbers is not as "obvious" as it might appear. There are better ways of showing that, but they require more machinery.

Although Euclid basically had all the tools required to prove the Unique Factorization Theorem for $\mathbb{N}$, the first proof is the one by Gauss, more than $2000$ years after Euclid.